# construct a new array from an array by filtering out null items

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct an array looping over another array which more or less looks like this

```
var x = [1, null, 324, 110, null]
```

I am trying to loop over this and check if an item at index i is not null then it goes into a new array

```
var numberCollection = [];

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    numberCollection[i] = (!!x[i]) ? x[i];
}

console.log(numberCollection)
```

which definitely does not work. What am I missing? I saw some examples of deleting an invalid item from an array but that is out of scope in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if (x[i] !== null){
      numberCollection.push(x[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: beat me by 34 seconds.

Comment: @ScottCorbett -- this one works..your work too. I see where my mistake was. Thanks for pointing at the right direction :-)

Comment: Just curious, why `!==` instead of just `!=`? The type comparison seems unnecessary in this case...

Comment: @MattBrowne. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons the link maybe have better explaining. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first array(the one that has NULLs) A[] and the second B[].  we will also need an int count.

```
for(var i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    if(A[i] != NULL){
        B[count] = A[i];
        count++;
    }
}
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work...just to give you another option, you could use the new `filter()` method introduced in ECMAScript 5:

```
var numberCollection = x.filter(function(item) {
    return !!item;
});
```

Note that for this to work in IE8 and below you'll need to provide a shim for the filter() method; there's one here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work fine.

```
var x = [1, null, 324, 110, null];
var numberCollection = [];

var k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] === null) {
        continue;
    } else {
        numberCollection[k++] = x[i];
    }
}

console.log(numberCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var numberCollection = [];
for(var i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i++){
    if (x[i] !== null) {numberCollection.push(x[i])}
}
```